# How to log an error's message without stack trace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stack-trace, traceback

I want to log that an error occurred without exiting from the program, so i enclose the code that might throw an error in a `try-catch` block like such

```
try
{
    let query = parseStatement(input); // might throw an error
    console.log(query);
}
catch (err)
{
    console.error(err); // logs the entire error with stack trace
}
finally
{
    this.prompt();
}
```

The output I would like to obtain is the error's message without the whole stack trace.
Something along the lines of:

`Error: Missing semicolon at the end of statement: <statement>`

and not

```
Error: Missing semicolon at the end of statement: <statement>
    at error (/home/nic/dev/nodedb/src/errors.js:5:11)
    at Function.tokenize (/home/nic/dev/nodedb/src/tokens.js:53:13)
    at parseStatement (/home/nic/dev/nodedb/src/sql.js:35:24)
    at Shell.onData (/home/nic/dev/nodedb/src/shell.js:49:25)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)
    at TTY.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't offer a real solution to the problem of logging without a stack trace; the accepted answer is wrong, and was written by the author himself.

Comment: I don't know, but to me this seems a bug in Firefox ? -- I sometimes see the stack trace expanded, and can not collapse it. Other times with the same code I see the stack trace collapsed, and can expand it _(e.g. after a browser re-start)_ -- I think `console.error` should not display the stack trace, but may provide it "collapsed" _(i.e. you would see the stack trace when you "expand" it)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message):

The `Error` object has a `.message` property, so instead of printing the whole error, just

```
console.error(error.message);
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone There was no such question/answer on SO, so i thought someone else might stumble upon the need to log an error without the whole stack trace. I think this question/answer might save someone else the time to read through the documentation

Comment: Even a plain text will have stack-trace. Not for itself. But for where you write the `console.error()`.

Comment: For me in nodejs this does not work. Even with just error.message it logs the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

With Node, you can simply use

> `process.exit()`

If you want to log a message - use `console.log/error` before exiting the process.

If you just want to remove stacktrace then you may do error.stack = "" before throwing the error like:-

```
const error = new Error("Your message");
error.stack = ""
throw error
```